# How to make a ssl certificates for my nodeJs Express WEB api thus run on my local network?

Tags: reactjs, axios, nodejs-express-server

I am trying to build a web api with hosted on my local network but the thing is my frontend website was deployed on web but i get this error on axios

```
AxiosError: Network Error
```

on my console it says this

```
XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myIPaddress:3000/get'. This request has been blocked; the 
content must be served over HTTPS.`
```

but when my frontend run on localhost it work fine

I try to search this error it says  i need to a SSL certificates

Comment: Are you loading your frontend (where the error shows up) via `http` or `https`? If you're using `https`, try changing the api route to `//myIPaddress:3000/get` (without the protocol)

Comment: thank you sir but it does not work im using http and i try to change it via https but it does not work or even //myIPaddress:3000/get this